# How show red colour border at edge of circle video cut out in ffmpeg?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I cut video in circle shape and overlay on image, every thing is work good but how to show red boarder at edge of circle video.

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i pic1.jpg -i semple.mp4 -filter_complex \
"[1]trim=end_frame=1,geq='st(3,pow(X-(W/2),2)+pow(Y-(H/2),2));if(lte(ld(3),pow(min(W/2,H/2),2)),255,0)':128:128,loop=-1:1,setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB[mask];[1][mask]alphamerge[cutout];[cutout]scale=400:400[cir];[0][cir]overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:(main_h-overlay_h)/2:shortest=1[out]" -map [out] -map 1:a -preset ultrafast -filter_complex_threads 1 -c:a copy -y output.mp4
```

please someone help.

Comment: Draw a slightly larger red circle before drawing the white circle

Comment: can you please share code because, I am new in ffmpeg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the cout out mask is merged, use geq to draw a red border of 10 pixels.

Use

`ffmpeg -loop 1 -i pic1.jpg -i semple.mp4 -filter_complex \
"[1]trim=end_frame=1,geq='st(3,pow(X-(W/2),2)+pow(Y-(H/2),2));if(lte(ld(3),pow(min(W/2,H/2),2)),255,0)':128:128,loop=-1:1,setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB[mask];[1][mask]alphamerge,format=yuva444p,geq='st(3,sqrt(pow(X-(SW*W/2),2)+pow(Y-(SH*H/2),2)));if(between(min(SW*W/2,SH*H/2)-ld(3),0,10),67,p(X,Y))':'st(3,sqrt(pow(X-(SW*W/2),2)+pow(Y-(SH*H/2),2)));if(between(min(SW*W/2,SH*H/2)-ld(3),0,10),90,p(X,Y))':'st(3,sqrt(pow(X-(SW*W/2),2)+pow(Y-(SH*H/2),2)));if(between(min(SW*W/2,SH*H/2)-ld(3),0,10),240,p(X,Y))':a='st(3,sqrt(pow(X-(SW*W/2),2)+pow(Y-(SH*H/2),2)));if(between(min(SW*W/2,SH*H/2)-ld(3),0,10),128,p(X,Y))',scale=400:400[cir];[0][cir]overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:(main_h-overlay_h)/2:shortest=1[out]" -map [out] -map 1:a -preset ultrafast -filter_complex_threads 1 -c:a copy -y output.mp4`

Comment: i am getting this output https://drive.google.com/file/d/1L_X7z9YLEPvCQQlEjySXitCpPoQqi31e/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Is there are two boarder at video circle black and red you can see above image ?

Comment: Edited cmd.....

Comment: Video showing squre instead circle you can see in image  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HKC2h4y2kKOgGwaAD2d3N_O1FfcrCZ2j/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Edited cmd.....

Comment: Use the first expression for `a=` as well, but change 255 to `0.5*255`

Comment: and one more thing can tell me why this process taking too much on android time, is there way to speed up this execution process in android ?

Comment: geq takes time as it works on each pixel individually.  If this is a regular task, generate a circular alpha mask and red border as images. Then just rescale them to fit video size.

Comment: Edited cmd......

Comment: above updated cmd still, take that much time and nothing change.

Comment: I only updated for opacity 0.5. You will have to generate the mask images in some other app.

Comment: Can you update code to `generate a circular alpha mask and red border as images. Then just rescale them to fit video size.` as you told above comment.